# Cannot export Java program to runnable JAR file in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a game made with LWJGL. When i run the game, it works fine but when i want export my game as runnable JAR file, Eclipse does nothing but when i reselect "Runnable JAR file". it shows me this error :
[eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNx8U.png)

Here is the Eclipse IDE log file :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.22.0.I20211124-1800
java.version=17.0.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.equinox.app
Error
Tue Aug 02 15:47:06 CEST 2022
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.app".

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4907)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4822)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.close(Shell.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.ui.splash.AbstractSplashHandler.dispose(AbstractSplashHandler.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3$1.applicationRunning(Workbench.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle$1.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.applicationRunning(EclipseAppHandle.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1091)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Please help me!

Comment: That log excerpt does not seem to contain this error.

Comment: Please be aware, that a project with a `module-info.java` file and dependencies cannot be exported to a runnable JAR because of limitations of Java. And there is a known issue in Eclipse which does not provide a proper error message in such a case.

Comment: @howlger I have no module-info.java in my project...

Comment: my bad... the problem is only with 'Runnable JAR file' option...

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by that. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).